# KivyMD Display Issue on Windows

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, interface, kivymd

Nothing is showing up in KivyMD on Windows. Buttons and images are not showing up, only a white window is displayed. What could be the problem? Please help me solve this issue.

I have created a project before where everything was displaying properly, but in this project, nothing is showing up and there are no errors.

I am trying to create a calculator using KivyMD, but I am facing issues with it from the beginning. I have created another project in the past using KivyMD and it worked fine, but in this project, nothing is displaying on the screen. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue